# framed losing context in def .cls

Tags: framed

[image]

This is the original layout.

The code that makes each line of the authors is this:

```
\def\@typeset@author@line{%
  \andify\@currentauthors\par\noindent
  \@currentauthors\def\@currentauthors{}%
  \ifx\@currentaffiliations\@empty\else
    \andify\@currentaffiliations
      \unskip, {\@currentaffiliations}\par
  \fi
  \def\@currentaffiliations{}
}
```

This is where it is instantiated:

```
\global\setbox\mktitle@bx=\vbox{\noindent\box\mktitle@bx\par\medskip
   \noindent\begin{framed}\addresses\@typeset@author@line\end{framed}
   \par\medskip}%
```

I changed the def of typeset@author@line to this:

```
\def\@typeset@author@line{%
    \begin{framed}
  \andify\@currentauthors\par\noindent
  \@currentauthors\def\@currentauthors{}%
  \ifx\@currentaffiliations\@empty\else
    \andify\@currentaffiliations
      \unskip, {\@currentaffiliations}\par
  \fi
  \def\@currentaffiliations{}
  \end{framed}
}
```

When I try to change the def of typeset@author@line, I get this result:
[image]

The latex is losing the context from what author it should be parsing and its doing everyone of them each line, incrementing by one for each line.
How can I keep the context working on this situation?
I want to add a framed for each line.

Answer (score 1):

I answered it myself after 30 seconds of posting the question... I don't feel really good about it but hey, no one knows when things will work out, I actually gave a little deeper thought on the latex after creating the question.

This is the way the def should be done to get the individual lines:

```
\def\@typeset@author@line{%
  \andify\@currentauthors\par\noindent
  \begin{framed}
  \@currentauthors
  \ifx\@currentaffiliations\@empty\else
    \andify\@currentaffiliations
      \unskip, {\@currentaffiliations}\par
  \fi
  \end{framed}
  \def\@currentauthors{}%
  \def\@currentaffiliations{}

}
```

The def@currentauthors{} and def@currentaffiliations{} is throwing out the knowledge about the line. So they had to be outside the {framed}, I don't know why though...
But it works!

Comment: Yes, `framed` (and all environments besides `document`) imply a local scope for definitions. In your case `\@currentauthors` and `\@currentaffiliations`.